# Golang doesn't process 2 operations

Tags: go

I'm a new in golang and i don't understand why I can't get next code working:

```
func ListApps(){
    fmt.Printf("\nPress Q to go back..\n")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    if string(input) == "q" {
        fmt.Printf("OK")
     }
 }
```

I want to print a message, then scan user's input in console, compare input and print messafe if imput equals string "q". Last check doesn't work for some reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from TFM:

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to **and including the delimiter**

You are comparing the string without the delimiter.

So just doing:

```
if input == "q\n" {...}
```

would work (BTW no need to call `string(input)` as input is already a string).

Alternatively you can also trim the endline before checking, using `strings.TrimRight`. This will make the code more portable as it will work on Windows where `\r\n` is used to delimit lines. So do this:

```
input = strings.TrimRight(input, "\r\n")
if input == "q" {
    fmt.Println("OK")
}
```

And I've tested this to work myself.

Comment: @Vnuuk it works for me. could be that your terminal is not using \n but \r\n. Which is why the second approach of trimming would work better, because it will be portable

Comment: Works, thanks! By the way - I'm useing Windows terminal

Answer (score 2):

Not_a_Golfer is correct on why its not working. However, for simple things like reading from STDIN you're better off using Scanner:

```
func ListApps(){
    fmt.Printf("\nPress Q to go back..\n")
    reader := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    reader.Scan()  // this line scans the STDIN for input

    // error checking...
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // To access what the scanner got, you use scanner.Text() (reader.Text() in this case)
    if reader.Text() == "q" {
        fmt.Printf("OK")
     }
 }
```

This will work, regardless of where the input is from (windows command prompt, terminal on linux/OSX, etc)